Recursive path travel in SPARQL
I am using Apache Jena 5.1.
Consider the following turtle format RDF.  The entities have all been collapsed
into 1 namespace for simplicity:
ex:thing1       ex:connectsTo   ex:thing2 .

ex:thing2       ex:connectsTo   ex:thing3, ex:thing4 .

ex:thing3       ex:connectsTo   ex:thing5 .

ex:thing7       ex:whatever     "not in this film" .

ex:thing8       ex:connectsTo   ex:thing5 .

I seek a SPARQL statement that an initial pipeline to produce 1 or more matches
for a subject e.g. ex:thing1 or (ex:thing1,ex:thing8) will produce
a proper recursive "from-to" result.
Assume we have a bound variable named components that can be 0 or more
of the ex:thingN entities.
If components is just ex:thing1 then the result will be
something like this.   I am not wed to this exact output format but the precise
walk down the dependency chain is critical.  Any alternative result from the
engine, for example individual from-to pairs, is fine.
ex:thing1 -> ex:thing2 -> ex:thing3 -> ex:thing5
ex:thing1 -> ex:thing2 -> ex:thing4

If components is (ex:thing1,ex:thing8) then the result will be:
ex:thing1 -> ex:thing2 -> ex:thing3 -> ex:thing5
ex:thing1 -> ex:thing2 -> ex:thing4
ex:thing8 -> ex:thing5

The closest I got is this:
SELECT DISTINCT ?start ?end
WHERE {
  # For simplicity just bind one value -- but ?components could be 2 or more!
  BIND(<http://example.org/foo#thing1> AS ?components)

  # Create the initial tree and get level 0 connectsTo:
  {
    ?components ex:connectsTo ?end .
    BIND(?components AS ?start)
  }
  UNION
  #  Now find all the rest:
  {
    ?start ex:connectsTo ?end .
    FILTER EXISTS {
      ?components ex:connectsTo+ ?start .
    }
  }
}

But the result coming back from Jena bizarrely includes ex:thing7.
UPDATED
Removing the FILTER EXISTS wrapper makes the query return the proper set of start-end pairs for any number of starting components.

running your query doesn't return ex:thing7 - neither with ex:thing1 being set as start nor without, so how do you get this back?

try this query, it will give you the intermediate edges for paths from start->end with start being given: `PREFIX : http://ex.org/
select * {
BIND(:thing1 AS ?start)
?start :connectsTo* ?from .
?from :connectsTo ?to .
?to :connectsTo* ?end .
FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?end :connectsTo [] }
}
order by ?start ?end`
